# Как написать оператор преобразования

Tags: c++

Есть какой то класс, например, класс комплексных чисел. Как для него должен выглядеть оператор преобразования ? например в int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно в определении класса добавить строчки подобные следуюшим:

```
class complex{
public:
operator int()      { return 1; } // оператор преобразования к int
...
}

// теперь мы можем сделать так:
complex cmp;
int a = (int)cmp; // присвоит переменной a значение 1
```

Если же Вам нужен конструктор объектов класса комплексных чисел из int, то это другой вопрос.

Comment: Если же Вам нужен конструктор объектов класса комплексных чисел из int, то это другой вопрос.
А это как сделать ?

Comment: добавить конструктор из int'ов:
<pre>class complex{
public:
   complex() {}
   complex(int a) {}
   complex(int a, int b) {}
   complex(int a, int b, int c) {}
}
...
// теперь можно сделать так:
complex* a =  new complex (10);</pre>

Comment: Логично, спасибо.
А нельзя как нибудь сделать так - 
int a = 10;
complex cmp = (complex)a;
или это невозможно ?

Comment: М-м-м-м... А зачем делать преобазование (complex)a?
Компилятор по идее сам при наличии кода сделает все сам.
<pre>//где-то в определении класса
complex& operator = (int);
...
// в коде
complex cmp; // создали объект с конструктором по умолчанию
int a = 10;
cmp = a; // допустимо, т.е. есть соответствующий перегруженный оператор</pre>